# Undefined property: stdClass::$contents in Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was studying and was a following a CodeIgniter Tutorial about database selecting methods. One of it's method was this one.

It was it's Model file called data_model.php:

```
<?php
    class Data_model extends CI_Model{
        function getAll(){
        $this->db->select('title','contents');
        $this->db->from('data');
        $this->db->where('id',1);           
        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;           
    }
}
?>
```

Controller File called site.php

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('data_model');
        $data['rows'] = $this->data_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('home',$data);        
    }   
}
?>
```

and View file called home.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>My view has been loaded.</p>         
            <?php foreach($rows as $r) : ?>
            <h1><?php echo $r->title; ?></h1>
            <div><?php echo $r->contents; ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When I try to run localhost/ci/ in my browser, an error occurs saying:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$contents
Filename: views/home.php
Line Number: 13
```

It seems like my $contents variable has no value, but I am pretty sure that my database has contents for each corresponding entry. Just like what the image below shows:

[image]

Where did I go wrong? The tutorial I was following didn't experience error? Why I am getting this error?

Comment: do print_r($rows);exit; and post output over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB active record library `select()` method takes input query fields in first param only that can array or string, see below

```
$this->db->select(array('title','contents'));
//OR
$this->db->select('title,contents');
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this will for for you

```
<?php
    class Data_model extends CI_Model{
        function getAll(){
        $this->db->select('title,contents');
        $this->db->from('data');
        $this->db->where('id',1);           
        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return $q->result(); 
        }          
    }
}
?>
```

and in view file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>My view has been loaded.</p>         
            <?php foreach($rows as $r) { ?>
            <h1><?php echo $r->title; ?></h1>
            <div><?php echo $r->contents; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>    
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```